# Thumbnail size problem Desktop vs Mobile site

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails, mobile

I have a problem with the thumbnail

I setup Customizing ▸ WooCommerce ▸ Product Images

The desktop page version shows a smaller thumbnail and the mobile site show the biggest version, Google page speed I got bad results because the mobile site is bigger than the desktop.
Category grid view have 100 pictures and too mutch size

So way working opposite?

Mobile site version picture size 68 Kb.
Desktop site version size 41 Kb.

Somebody can check reakiroshop.eu

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
enter image description here

Comment: Image sizes can come from either a theme or a plugin, so I would test a different theme on a staging site and see if it gets any different results. If so, see how you can customize image sizes in a child theme. If not, try turning off plugins until you find what's causing the issue. If you're lucky and the plugin is actively supported you may get help and even a fix through the plugin dev, but if not you can likely override their sizes as well in either a child theme or custom plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I forgot to write I checked this:

- changed theme
- resize all image
- switch off all plugins.
 I have 2 different sites and working the same ... Mobile site thumbnail is bigger than the Desktop. Mobile site page speed is not good, because load full images like an attached picture original post.

No have more ideas... anybody can check this fact owned site, please?

Answer (score 0):

I also got exactly this problem. This is not theme related, or, if it is, there is ALOT of themes with this problem.

Currently having the same issue on Oxygenbuilder pages.